# Jupyter Notebooks Not Opening in Web Browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0. In terminal upon running `jupyter notebook` I get directed to Jupyter labs in my browser. The folder directory (http://localhost:8888/tree) displays all files, however individual files do not open and I receive a loading, and then the page 'dies'. In Chrome, this is the 'Aw Snap' message with error code 5. Any idea what is going on here?

[Jupyterlab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2v03.png)

A few other details that may or may not be relevant...

```
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.22.0
ipykernel        : 5.5.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.14
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

And here is the output from terminal

[terminal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0g0V.png)